# Is it possible to deduce the derivatives of sine and cosine without geometry and "cheating?"

Tags: functions, derivatives, trigonometry, functional-equations, alternative-proof

I am asking if it's possible to find the derivatives without geometry, circular thinking, and definitions that don't make sense to introduce based on the intuitive meaning of sine and cosine (i.e that assume you already know the answer.)

Note: I take the Pythagorean identity, the zeroth and first derivatives at zero, and that sine is odd and cosine is even to be used as the definitions for sine and cosine.

Edit: I will also assume they are bounded by $1$ and $-1$ and never constant on a continuous interval.

I tried using the Pythagorean theorem and that sine is odd and cosine is even and reached that $$\cos\theta+i\sin\theta=e^{g(\theta)}$$ where $g$ is an odd function. However, I couldn't prove that $g''=0$ (equivilant to $g''$ is even) which we can use (along with $\sin'(0)=1$ and $\cos'(0)=0$) to deduce $g=i\theta$.

So, I thought maybe it's much easier. If we differentiate the Pythagorean identity, we get:
$$\sin\theta\sin'\theta=-\cos\theta\cos'\theta\tag{$\star$}\label{1}$$
Squaring both sides to avoid multiple cases for the signs, we get:
$$(\sin\theta\sin'\theta)^2=(\cos\theta\cos'\theta)^2$$
What are the possibilities here?

We certainly know $\sin^2\theta≠\cos^2\theta$ and $(\sin'\theta)^2≠(\cos\theta\cos'\theta)^2$, so it seems that the only possibility is:
$$(\sin'\theta)^2=(\cos\theta)^2\\
(\cos'\theta)^2=(\sin\theta)^2$$
My question is: Is this logic true, can we prove such a thing? If so, we can proceed as follows, differentiate the equations:
$$\sin'\theta\sin''\theta=\cos\theta\cos'\theta\\
\cos'\theta\cos''\theta=\sin\theta\sin'\theta$$
Now, substitute from $\eqref{1}$:
$$\sin''\theta=-\sin\theta\\
\cos''\theta=-\cos\theta$$
Afterwards, we can use ansatz $e^{\lambda\theta}$ and the zeroth and first derivatives at $0$ to solve for the exponential forms of sine and cosine. As a result, we can deduce the derivatives and the angle-sum formulas too.

Comment: What is your definition of sine and cosine? Which identities do you allow yourself?

Comment: Here is a way to define everything from scratch. https://deaneyang.github.io//blog/blog/math/exponential-function/euler-formula/2022/06/05/ExponentialFunction.html

Comment: Choose any $a>0$, let $s(x)$ be $\sin x$ for $|x|\le a$, $s(x)=\sin a$ for $|x|\ge a$, similarly, $c(x)=\cos x$ for $|x|\le a$, $c(x)=\cos a$ for $|x|\ge a$. I think these functions satisfy all your requirements, but they aren't sine and cosine.

Comment: As far as I can tell the 'definition' you give isn't sufficient to give $\sin$ and $\cos$. Consider the function which is $\sin(\theta)$ for $\theta$ close to zero, but which 'speeds up' for $\theta$ away from zero. This satisfies your definition, but isn't $\sin$. You might be able to get 'local' derivative results however.

Comment: How is your definition "intuitive"? What kind of intuition is it based on?

Comment: @DavidK You have to assume something, otherwise you can prove nothing. I chose to assume the Pythagorean identity (which depends on geometry) and the other identities listed above, but I chose not to involve any other form of geometry that relates specifically to sine and cosine, i.e you can argue derivatives use geometry but they are not specific for sine and cosine, the angle-sum formulas (that are proved by geometry) are the more conventional way to approach this problem, but I am trying to avoid them to see how far we can go and to investigate.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I will assume they are bounded by $1$ and $-1$ and are never constant on a continuous interval, but I think though not exactly sure, we can still have some functions that aren't sine and cosine, in that case I will also need to specify they are periodic. But we'll keep it this way until maybe someone provides these other functions.

Comment: @Feshbane, I want you to read the above comment too.

Comment: I suggest that in the future, before you post a question, you think it through and include all the conditions you wish to impose on the answers, rather than letting people waste their time and yours by coming up with solutions you don't like. Alternatively, accept the answers you don't like and then post a new question (with links between the old and new questions) imposing the conditions you neglected to include on the old question. Anyway, with a little imagination, I'm sure you can come up with functions that will meet your new conditions – but I won't. I'm outta here.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I really hoped that while using this website, answerers would actually be trying to help, not merely criticising and attacking, especially those with high reputation that think users with low reputation are just stupid or something despite that they are the ones who are trying to just give a quick answer like no your definition doesn't work like a computer that doesn't know any better. That's why I choose to delete my account. I'm outta here.

Comment: I did try to help you, mohamed, and so did several other users. I don't think you're stupid, and I doubt other users think that. I'm sorry you haven't found what you wanted here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Note: I take the Pythagorean identity, the zeroth and first derivatives at zero, and that sine is odd and cosine is even to be used as the definitions for sine and cosine.

This is not enough to uniquely specify sine and cosine. These conditions are satisfied, for example, by the real and imaginary parts of $e^{i (\theta + \theta^3)}$, namely $c(\theta) = \cos(\theta + \theta^3)$ and $s(\theta) = \sin(\theta + \theta^3)$.

However, the following conditions are similar to yours and *do* uniquely specify sine and cosine: they are the unique pair of differentiable functions $c(\theta), s(\theta)$ satisfying

- $c(0) = 1, s(0) = 0$,
- $c'(0) = 0, s'(0) = 1$,
- $c(\theta)^2 + s(\theta)^2 = 1$, and
- $c'(\theta)^2 + s'(\theta)^2 = 1$.

These conditions say that $\theta \mapsto (c(\theta), s(\theta))$ is a unit speed parameterization of the unit circle starting at $(1, 0)$ and moving counter-clockwise. Writing $v(\theta) = (c(\theta), s(\theta))$, differentiating the third condition $\| v \|^2 = 1$ gives $\langle v, v' \rangle = 0$, which together with the fourth condition $\| v' \|^2 = 1$ gives that $v'$ always differs from $v$ by a $90^{\circ}$ rotation (which the initial conditions imply is counter-clockwise). This gives $c'(\theta) = s(\theta), s'(\theta) = - c(\theta)$ as desired. From here we can get to Euler's formula, etc.

Of course one still has to prove that such a pair of functions exists.

Comment: Not criticizing for the sake of criticising, but **I think** (but I may be wrong) that there are a few issues here which should be eliminated : (1) When saying that $v$ & $v'$ Differ by $90^0$ , we are using geometry in Disguise, which OP wants to avoid. (2) Why should it be $90^0$ ? Why not $360+90^0$ ? (3) When saying it is unit Parameterization of unit Circle, we are using geometry. (4) When saying $<v,v'>=0$ in case $v$ & $v'$ are Perpendicular , we are using geometry. (5) This is very close to geometric Interpretation of the values. [[ over all , good thinking , +1 ]]

Comment: It also follows if $c'(\theta)^2+s'(\theta)^2=1$ that $g'(\theta)=\pm i$ and we can solve for $g$ using the derivatives at $0$ which is better because it doesn't require geometry which I try to stay away from as @Prem pointed out. Good answer anyway.

Comment: I actually knew that it has to happen that we use $c'(\theta)^2+s'(\theta)^2=1$, but I couldn't prove it or deduce it intuitively.

Answer (score 2):

There are Multiple Issues here :

(1) When you take these Criteria :
"(1A) Pythagorean identity, (1B) the zeroth at zero (1C) first derivatives at zero, & (1D) sine is odd & cosine is even"
Then there are Multiple Solutions which will work & we will not get $\sin$ & $\cos$.

We might take the Example of $\sin{\theta^{3}}$ & $\cos{\theta^{3}}$ which also will satisfy all the Criteria.
Solution is not unique.
[[ Correction based on Comment by user "Gerry Myerson" ]]

(2) When you say "We certainly know [squares are not Equal]" how can we say that without "cheating" or without knowing geometry + trigonometry ?
[[ We know this only @ $\theta=0$ , but it might be equal elsewhere ]]

(3) When you say "We certainly know [Derivative with squares are not Equal]" how can we say that without "cheating" or without knowing Derivative in advance ?
[[ We know this only @ $\theta=0$ , but it might be equal elsewhere ]]

(4) When we Square it to avoid negative sign, we will get more solutions into the picture.
[[ OP has mentioned that we can go back to original Equation to eliminate the unwanted solutions , which is correct & hence this Point (4) is then not valid ]]

(5) When we have $(AB)^{2}=(CD)^{2}$ & somehow know that $(A)^{2}$ is not $(C)^{2}$ & $(B)^{2}$ is not $(CD)^{2}$ , we can not conclude that $(A)^{2}$ is $(D)^{2}$ & $(B)^{2}$ is $(C)^{2}$

We can take the Example of the Integer Case where $(A,B,C,D)$ is $(2,4,1,8)$
[[ In Current Case, OP wants to show that what we have is actually $(AB)^{2}=(BA)^{2}$ which requires more analysis ]]

In short, this current approach specifically will not work & we have to use geometry + trigonometry to get the Derivative.
More-over, there can be no theoretical approach in general which can avoid geometry when using this Assumption or Definition : Sine & Cosine are the ratios of the right angle triangle.
That is because , no matter what calculations we use , we have to eventually show that it is equal to the ratios of the right angle triangle.

Proof By Contradiction :
Assume that we can deduce Sine & Cosine without geometry. Assume that we can  then show that it is Exactly Equal to trigonometry Sine & Cosine.
Then this means we have shown the validity of Euclidean Geometry without using geometry , which means Parallel Postulate is absolutely true & all other geometries (Riemann & Lobachevski) are not true.
Naturally, we have to go back on our Assumption & conclude that Sine & Cosine are inherently geometric & are Euclidean Geometry Products.

This Answer is contrary to the Accepted Answer [[ which I have upvoted , seeing the interesting idea & the nice approach ]] which is actually using geometry in Disguise even though OP wants to avoid that.

Comment: I think $\sin^3x$ and $\cos^3x$ don't satisfy Pythagoras. $\exists x:\sin^6x+\cos^6x\ne1$.

Comment: ($2$) is by definition. ($3$) is because then $\sin(\theta)$ would be $\pm 1$ which is not odd. The idea is not to completely throw intuition out of the window, I am investigating other ways to arrive at the ideas we already know. ($4$) is because we reuse the original equation by substituting after differentiating. I am not saying ($5$) is true, I am asking if there's a proof, maybe proving sine and cosine are transcendental functions so we can do what I am asking. That's the whole point of the question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, yeah that's also true because:
$$s^6+c^6=(s^2)^3+(c^2)^3\\
=(s^2+c^2)(s^4-s^2c^2+c^4)\\
=s^4-s^2c^2+c^4\\
=s^4+2s^2c^2+c^4-3s^2c^2\\
=(s^2+c^2)^2-3s^2c^2\\
=1-3s^2c^2\\
=1-\frac34\sin^2(2x)\overset{?}=1\\
\sin(2x)=0\implies x=\frac{n\pi}{2},n\in\mathbb{Z}$$
So, it's not true $\forall x$.

Comment: More simply, $\sin^6(\pi/6)+\cos^6(\pi/6)=(1/2)^6+(\sqrt3/2)^6=(1/64)+(27/64)\ne1$.

Comment: Thanks for catching that Issue @GerryMyerson , I have corrected it. I have also added a Proof By Contradiction , hope you can check that & let me know your thoughts.

Comment: I have edited my Answer according to your comments , @mohamedshawky , hope you can check it again. I have also added a Proof By Contradiction , hope you can check that & let me know your thoughts.

Comment: The definition $s^2+c^2=1$ is for all angles, so it can't be $s^2=c^2$. I like your proof though I don't understand it that much, but I'd like if you read my comment under the accepted answer. I accepted it because it confirmed that we need $s'^2+c'^2=1$ as another definition if we wish to define sine and cosine uniquely, I am still not quite sure though if we can use weaker assumption like periodicity and boundedness that I explained in the comments.

Comment: As I said, I'm trying to see what definitions we need to define sine and cosine uniquely. I also said in a comment under the question, you have to assume something, or you'll prove nothing, that's why we have to assume the Pythagorean identity though it's geometric. I am trying to explore the OTHER ways that don't use the angle sum formulas. Thank you.